# Lubuntu doesn't take full advantage of my wireless speed capabilities

Tags: networking, wireless, drivers, lubuntu

I already did a search through SO, the forums, etc. for issues that looked related to Ubuntu and my Wireless card, but I didn't find anything that was obviously relevant that worked.

First, the system information:

```
% lsb_release -a
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty


% sudo lshw -C network 
... (skipping ethernet card info)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Centrino Advanced-N 6230 [Rainbow Peak]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 34
       serial: 88:53:2e:52:ee:41
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-43-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 ip=192.168.1.184 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
       resources: irq:56 memory:f6200000-f6201fff
```

This card is rated for 300Mbps, but the most I get out of it is 100Mbps speeds.  I have Google Fiber Gigabit internet.  My MacBook pro was downloading at 400+Mbps.

I tried the solutions at http://itsfoss.com/speed-up-slow-wifi-connection-ubuntu/, but none of them seemed to work, so I reverted the changes I had made.

Normally I use nmcli to connect to the internet (nmcli dev wifi connect  password ).  I tried wicd but didn't notice a difference with that, either.

There's one site that suggested that I would have to change the Grub bootloader to include the option GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="biosdevname=0".  I don't feel comfortable doing that until I'm sure it applies, though, because I'm not sure the realtek stuff applies to my system (ref: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2192746).

How should I continue trouleshooting why my connection speeds are slower than what's rated for the card/chipset?

Comment: 100 Mbps is a very good result for a "300Mbps marketing name" wireless card. Theoretical limit for it less than 150 Mbps.

Comment: Make sure your wifi router is using WPA2-AES or WPA2 only and try 'echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8" | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf` and reboot

Comment: Could you [follow this advice](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205) and report back?

Comment: @Fabby: I was under the impression this was due to the limitations of my card, as indicated by Pilot6.  However, I will try Jeremy31's suggestion at your request before replacing my wireless card.

Comment: It's limited by your environment.  Running that script will allow us to positively tell you (or not) that it *indeed* is a maximum before you go out and replace your card (and router!!!)